# Whici tablet computer to write mathematics in a car?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

*(I don't know if asking this question here is ok, so please let me know if another forum is best suited.)*

I am studying mathemetics on a graduate level while working and I was wondering if someone knows a good tablet computer to do my exercices on and take notes in a car.
Indeed, I spent some time inside my car at work and I would like to have a device that can be used vertically (tactile, not with a keyboard) and usable during nighttime.

Most of the mundane computer tablets are not precise enough to write small details, that is why I am looking for something more specific. Maybe drawing tablets ?

Please let me know if you have any experience in this matter.

Comment: I use an old wacom bamboo, without built in screen nor big size(its almost like an ebook), but its like writing with pen and paper even though its small.

Comment: but anyways i dont think this belongs here

Comment: @Garmekain I agree that it doesn't belong here.  Ironically, however, I would place a lot of trust in any *answer* re this question that was posted on mathSE.

Comment: @Garmekain Thanks, going to check that out !

Comment: @user2661923 Couldn't agree more :) that is my I first posted it here

Comment: Thats true @user

Comment: @Garmekain I just checked it out, very nice product, I had no idea such a tablet existed !

Comment: Yeah notebooks do stack on top of each other...

Comment: And you can touch the "screen" with your hand. Thats a big up.